# Linux usbmount: Determining Which Mounting Points Are Truly Active

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, usb

Running Rasbian Buster Lite headless no desktop, I am using usbmount to automount usb storage drives.
By default it sets them to /media/usb0, /media/usb1, ... /media/usb7; however, these mount points exist whether there is any usb drive in at all.  I can even write files to these folders when nothing is plugged in and see them with `ls`.  **My question is how can I determine whether these mount points are real or not**

Background: Trying to make a script that saves files to USB sticks without any user intervention other than plugging a usb drive in and swapping it out later with a new usb stick.

Linux novice, so would appreciate any extra explanation that can be offered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently active mount points can be determined by :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r real on mount _; do
    if  fdisk -l | grep -q "^$real"; then
        echo "$real is mounted on $mount"
    fi
done < <(mount | grep "on /media")
```

Save above script in test.sh, then run

```
chmod +x test.sh
./test.sh
```

Comment: Thanks Philippe!  I just tried testing this and I am sometimes getting false positives if I have recently pulled a USB drive w/o unmounting.  Is there any way to resolve this with a script?  I don't want the people retrieving the drives to have to bring a laptop, ssh in, and gracefully unmount the old drives.  I need to keep their involvement as simple as pulling out the old drive and plugging in a new one, but if I can make an automated script to fix these false positives, that would be great.

Comment: If you see `/dev/sdb1 on /media/usb0`, and user unplugged without properly unmounting, the you can check if `/dev/sdb1` is in the list returned by `fdisk -l`.

Comment: ok thanks! Is there a way to parse out this very long result?  I see how I can run your commands manually then manually interpret, but am rather noobish at how I would extract the part of the result I need to automatically interpret an answer.  Thank you so much

Comment: @rfii  Please edit your Q to show a small sample of output from both `mount | grep 'on /media'` and `fdisk -l` where some sample `/dev/sdbN`s that are in the first output AND include one output that should be ignored. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you!  Although the non-existent drives was happening all weekend while I've been tryng to figure it out, of course I haven't been able to make it happen in the last two hours, but will post the results when I do.  Thank you Philippe for your edited code.  I think it's working and will keep testing!